# Should I use Athena views to do joins for Quicksight or should I do them in Quicksight?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

I have a bunch of Athena tables generated from data I pump into S3 on an ongoing basis and I would like to use that data with QuickSight.
I have some success but for some data I get timeouts while refreshing QS. Am I better off doing views in Athena to do all the joins etc and then slurping that into QS for reporting or should I be slurping the base tables into QS and doing joining and other data manipulation there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athena views aren't materialized views so they aren't so beneficial for you.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/when-to-use-views.html

Instead of that I suggest to transform your data by using AWS Glue job before loading to QS.
You can consider also partitioning or compresion of your source data. I use often also parquet format with snappy compression.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-tips-for-amazon-athena/

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is if you are doing all the joins in Athena, the dataset size may be larger and need more QS storage.
QS now allows to join to QS Dataset as well.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/joining-data.html

Also if using this approach, the size of the tables being joined to is limited.